# Grails: links for text files

Tags: grails, model-view-controller, gsp

In my Grails app I need to serve links to actual text (`*.txt`) files. If the user clicks the link, they should view the text file as plaintext inside their browser:

```
MyFiles.groovy controller:
==========================
class MyFiles {
    def index() {
        render(view: "myfiles")
    }
}

myfiles.gsp:
============
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <!-- Omitted for brevity -->
    </head>
    <body>
        <a href="??? myfile01.txt ???">Click me to view a file</a>
    </body>
</html>
```

My questions:

1. Where should I place `myfile01.txt` inside the Grails project? Directly inside `web-app`? Inside a `web-app/myfiles` dir? Inside `WEB-INF`?; and
2. What should the link be in the GSP, such that Grails correctly resolves correctly and displays the file? I don't see anything under [`g:links`](http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Tags/link.html) that stands out as an obvious choice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd recommend creating another folder where you have images/css.

```
<a href='<g:resource dir="somedirectory" file=myfiles01.txt" absolute="true" />'>my file</a>
```